# Select Top 50 Friends for App Requests

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, apprequests, multi-friend-selector

Does anyone know how to make your request dialog for your facebook app select your top 50 friends like this: http://www.insidesocialgames.com/2011/10/18/new-facebook-game-invite-tool-streamlines-friend-requests-process/

It seems like it's a special thing only the top facebook games get to use or something.  I can't find a single line of documentation about it anywhere online.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the article that's something that LOLapps implemented themselves using Frictionless Requests (which are documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

Essentially, with frictionless requests, the user can choose when sending a request to allow the app to send requests to the same person in future without the (sending) user needing to confirm each request.

It looks like that option in the selector is used by LOLapps to signify 'choose this, and we'll send requests automatically to your top 50 friends' - but only those friends that the user has already sent something to, and enabled the frictionless option for.